# AWS Enviroment fails to connect with the Database

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created a simple Spring Boot application in IntelliJ and tested the connection with the AWS database, which gives me no error. After creating a mvn clean install, I test the jar in the command-prompt, which also gives me no error. Great, I can upload my JAR file to my AWS Environment. I go to Environment > Configuration > Edit Database, and select my database in the snapshot drop down. But my Environment wound connect  to the database. I don't get why it would work. I've been trying to run my app on AWS for days now and I feel I'm close, but don't know how to solve this problem. Plz check out my log:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Apr 20 06:15:19 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 06:15:19.048:INFO::main: Logging initialized @367ms
Apr 20 06:15:19 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 06:15:19.122:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
Apr 20 06:15:19 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 06:15:19.201:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@2fcb66eb{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:5000}
Apr 20 08:34:45 ip-172-31-35-71 web: :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.6)
Apr 20 08:34:45 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:45.466  INFO 11107 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringBootCrudExampleApplication   : Starting SpringBootCrudExampleApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.14.1 on ip-172-31-35-71.ec2.internal with PID 11107 (/var/app/current/application.jar started by webapp in /var/app/current)
Apr 20 08:34:45 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:45.477  INFO 11107 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringBootCrudExampleApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Apr 20 08:34:47 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:47.473  INFO 11107 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Apr 20 08:34:47 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:47.963  INFO 11107 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 472 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
Apr 20 08:34:49 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:49.554  INFO 11107 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
Apr 20 08:34:49 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:49.582  INFO 11107 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
Apr 20 08:34:49 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:49.583  INFO 11107 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
Apr 20 08:34:49 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:49.769  INFO 11107 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Apr 20 08:34:49 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:49.769  INFO 11107 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4143 ms
Apr 20 08:34:50 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:50.856  INFO 11107 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
Apr 20 08:34:50 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:50.987  INFO 11107 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.7.Final
Apr 20 08:34:51 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:51.362  INFO 11107 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Apr 20 08:34:51 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:51.585  INFO 11107 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
Apr 20 08:34:51 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:51.957  INFO 11107 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
Apr 20 08:34:51 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:51.979  INFO 11107 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Apr 20 08:34:53 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:53.137  INFO 11107 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Apr 20 08:34:53 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:53.148  INFO 11107 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Apr 20 08:34:54 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:54.000  WARN 11107 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
Apr 20 08:34:54 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:54.946  INFO 11107 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path ''
Apr 20 08:34:54 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:34:54.965  INFO 11107 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringBootCrudExampleApplication   : Started SpringBootCrudExampleApplication in 11.253 seconds (JVM running for 12.875)
Apr 20 08:36:29 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:36:29.654  INFO 11107 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Apr 20 08:36:29 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:36:29.658  INFO 11107 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
Apr 20 08:36:29 ip-172-31-35-71 web: 2022-04-20 08:36:29.690  INFO 11107 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Events

INFO Environment health has transitioned from Warning to Ok.

WARN Environment health has transitioned from Warning to Ok.

INFO The environment was reverted to the previous configuration setting.

INFO Environment health has transitioned from Info to Warning. Configuration update failed 18 seconds ago and took 67 seconds.
The environment was reverted to the previous configuration setting.
Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Configuration update in progress (running for 15 seconds).

ERROR Failed to deploy configuration.

ERROR Creating RDS database failed Reason: DB Instance class db.t2.micro does not support encryption at rest

ERROR Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-3a2mk3bca7-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].

INFO Updating environment Invoice-env's configuration settings.

INFO Environment update is starting.

Comment: Where in the log does it say connection to DB problems..?

Comment: I've edit my post with a number of events right after trying to connect the database It seems it has to doe something with the AmazonCloudFormation?

Comment: I am sorry to say this @Flying Nimbus, but your question is very vague. Are you deploying resources via cloudformation? The logs say you are creating a database. The error message is very clear, with the db instance type selected you can't have encryption at rest. Either you change the instance type or 'deselect' encryption at rest.

Comment: It seems like you are running into an issue creating an RDS database in CloudFormation, but you are focusing on your Spring Boot server's logs for some reason. You need to focus on the CloudFormation configuration. Until CloudFormation can create the database server, there will be nothing for your Spring Boot application to connect to.

Comment: Thx @Mark B I found it out